# Convert vector<string> to QVector<QString>

Tags: c++, qt

What is the most basic way to convert a `std::vector<std::string>` to `QVector<QString>`?

```
std::vector<std::string> plain = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "mango", "blueberry"};
QVector<QString> qt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a one-line but a two-liner...

```
QVector<QString> qt;
std::transform(plain.begin(), plain.end(), std::back_inserter(qt), [](const std::string &v){ return QString::fromStdString(v); });
```

And as addendum to taiwan12's answer and mine as well I would suggest you should use `qt.reserve(plain.size());` before adding the strings. Which would make my answer three-liner. What a shame!

Regarding performance, my measurements show that both solutions (mine and taiwan12's) work equally fast.

Comment: `reserve` method is a unbelievable good practise